# flask sqlalchemy update error - update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am building a restful-api with flask-restful. The code below is the [PUT]users/ api, which accepts variable named email through json, and parses through reqparse, which is a method given by flask-restful.

```
class UserAPI(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('email', type=str,
            help='No Email Provided', location='json')
        super(UserAPI, self).__init__()
    def put(self,id):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        user = User.update(email=args.email) #this is the code causing error
        return {id:user.email}
api.add_resource(UserAPI, '/api/users/<int:id>', endpoint='user')
```

The method "update" is a customized function looks like this:

```
def update(self, commit=True, **kwargs):
        """Update specific fields of a record."""
        for attr, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, attr, value)
        return commit and self.save() or self
```

However, when I send [put] command of {"email":"admin@amdin.com"} to localhost/api/users/, It gives me the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 265, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 265, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\__init__.py", line 124, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 446, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_httpauth.py", line 61, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NI\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 550, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NI\projects\nektime\nektime\public\views.py", line 76, in put
    user = User.update(email=args.email)
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: It's hard to see fro your code above: How is update defined? Is it a method of a class or a function? If it is a function (not inside a class) that would explain the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling update on the User class rather than an instance of User. You could instantiate the User before calling update:

```
user = User.query.get(id)
user.update(email=args.email)
```

Or you could make update a @classmethod and have it take the cls as the first argument rather than self and it would instantiate a User.